# Calculating overlap between routes

Tags: routes, tomtom

If two routes are calculated using the TomTom Routing (Web or SDK), is there a way to calculate the amount of overlap between these?

Comment: The longer one is just the same path, but longer?

Comment: The two routes can have the same source and destination or, E.g. different sources but same destination or completely independent spurces and destinations. However, the might share same roads. The question is how to find these overlaps and calculate their lengths.

Comment: Compare the routes. If thelonger contains the shorter one then take the destination of the shorter and set as the source and copy the destination from the longer one. Then just do a query to Routing API. In the response you can find the distance.

Comment: 1) How would carry out the comparison? 
2) This method only works if both paths share the same "final segment" but does not generalize to all combinations.

Answer (score 0):

@navid - It may be late reply

1. You have array of Steps (list of lat/long) for both routes
   say A=(p1,p2),B=(p3,p4)
2. Convert each elements of both Array using geohash
3. Now it will be bit easy comparison of Two routes, like comparing elements of two sets/array.